# Passing paramaters of an Javafx Controller to another one?

Tags: javafx, controller, label

i got a problem with a project i´m doing right now, im working with JavaFx, and I need to pass the text inside of an Label in the class ListController to the class List2Controller, and then show the text in another label on List2Controller.
The label in ListController obviously has a text inside.

This is what im doing, but isnt working:

ListController.java

```
private Label nit;
private String var1;
public void setVar1(String var1)
{
    this.var1=var1;
}

public String getVar1()
{
         return var1;
}
```

List2Controller.java

```
 private Label name;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    String n = null;
     ListController f = new ListController();
     String valorVar1 = f.getVar1();
     name.setText(valorVar1);
}
```

Comment: `ListController f = new ListController()` doesn't give you the controller - it just gives you another instance of the same class.

Comment: Then, how can I solve my stuff?

Comment: See linked question, it shows several techniques for doing exactly this. I was just explaining why your code didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, didn´t see it. Thanks